# logic to add a video as favourite.

Tags: php, mysql, html

Lets say I have a website that allows users to view videos. I want to implement the feature where a user can click on buttons beside the video and 'Favourite' it or mark it as "Favourite" and display the list of favourites to specific user. When the user exits the website and returns another day, those videos he marked will be in his favourites

How do i go about to achieve this. Please help as i am new to coding.

Comment: This suggestion isn't worthy enough to be an answer, but you could store the favorites in JSON format and store it in a cell in a database, but this is probably a terrible way of approaching this problem.

Answer (score 3):

Create a new table called `favorites`. In this table have columns id, user, video.

The field "id" would be the primary key of this table. The field user should contain the user id (from a table of users you already should have, if you don't create one). Also, the video column should contain just a reference ID for the video, and have another table where you contain your videos.

When a user clicks on "add to favorites" your script should retrieve the user ID from the session variables or from the database, and also the video ID. Then simply store these with an INSERT into your `favorites` table.

To present a list of favorite videos to users, simply SELECT * FROM `favorites` WHERE `user_id` = $user_id;

Note: You populate $user_id with the current logged in user's ID, either via your session variables or database, whichever stores your session data.

Comment: Registered users can only add favorites to the videos. In this case User must loged into your website to click favorite button.

Comment: @ George Violaris: Thanks alot. Bt will u plzz explain the flow of how to go about this whole activity. i mean the tables code and all.

Comment: @ Tharanga Nuwan: i have a user table which is maintaining the list of username and password. how will i differentiate that a particular video is favourites to that particular user and no one else can view it.

Comment: @niuu I can help if you ask me specific questions, what to you mean by the flow? Also I can't just give you the code if you don't try... Make some attempts and if you don't succeed then paste us your work and I'll take a look and help if needed.

Comment: @niuu it is easy follow George Violaris's answer and come again with your experiments.

Comment: Thanks all for ua answers ...i have done with the fav creation.

Comment: Hey, this is unrelated to your original question and you should open up another one.

Answer (score 0):

Add an entry to a [Junction table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table) where one column is the id of the user and the other column is the id of the video.

Comment: can u explain the logic of doing this.

Comment: 1. Get id of user. 2. Set id of video. 3. Make SQL insert statement with those two bits of data.

Comment: i have one more question. I have 2 folders on my Home page: Public and  Private. I want the Private folder should be viewed only by that particular user. How should i link the user id with the private folder contents.